# AWS Lambda + python: ec2.start_instances(InstancesIds= ?? )

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created the below python script in AWS Lambda, to list all the stopped instances, which works well. now, I wants to extend the functionality by starting the instances which were stopped.

**Script:**

```
region ='us-east-1'
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',region)
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['stopped']}])
    for instance in instances:
        print('Ec2 Instances which are stopped: ', 'Instance ID: ', instance.id, 'Instance state: ', instance.state, 'Instance type: ',instance.instance_type)
```

Now am appending the following code to start the instances:

```
ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=instance.id)
```

I am getting error[ec2.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'start_instances], because (InstanceIds=' ') expects list here,
but my instance is of type `<class 'boto3.resources.factory.ec2.Instance'>`
How do i convert, so that I can input list to start_instances method.

Thanks in Advance!!

Please find below, my updated script after getting answer, now this script will start the stopped instances automatically.

**Updated script**

```
region ='us-east-1'
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2',region)
client = boto3.client('ec2',region)
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['stopped']}])
    for instance in instances:
        print('Ec2 Instances which are stopped: ', 'Instance ID: ', instance.id, 'Instance state: ', instance.state, 'Instance type: ',instance.instance_type)
        instance_ids = [instance.id for instance in instances]
        response = client.start_instances(InstanceIds=[instance.id])
        print('Lambda have started these instances', instance.id)
```

**Caution** Please exercise care if you are copy pasting this script as this will turn-on instances which may cost you. (This script is working, TESTED!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ec2.instances](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#service-resource) is the higher level [resource](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/resources.html) and [start_instance](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#instance) is low level [client](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/clients.html), to use the client function, you need create the client with `boto3.client('ec2')`

```
client = boto3.client('ec2')
response = client.start_instances(
    InstanceIds=[
        'string',
    ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start each instance in the loop:

```
ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=[instance.id])
```

If you want to start all instances outside the loop: Use list comprehension to generate a list of instance ids and pass it to `start_instances`

```
instance_ids = [instance.id for instance in instances]
ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=instance_ids)
```

Comment: I tried converting it to list, Its not working.. since the instance.id is of type  <class 'boto3.resources.factory.ec2.Instance'> which is not getting converted into list.

Comment: Are you sure? instance.id is a string.

Comment: When I checked the type of instance.id It shows this  <class 'boto3.resources.factory.ec2.Instance'> and I also tried both of your suggestions. I am getting error ec2.ServiceResource' object has no attribute 'start_instances'

Comment: Thanks for your effort @helloV !!